# Make scrolling overlay click through

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I have a big gantt chart to show on mobile and it must be scrollable. That is when I created a `div.scroll-overlay` at the same level using for scrolling purpose. However, as well as its supporting for swipe scrolling, it prevents us from all the `touch actions` that supported by the `div.content` and inside - We are unable to **click** by touching on the `div.content` no more. I trial and error with CSS `touch-action` and `event-pointer` but nothing works so far.

**Problem**

- Need `div.scroll-overlay` so that we can scroll on mobile but because of it we cannot touch/click `div.content`
- Cannot scroll directly on `div.content` since it has too many `touch actions` behind the scene that prevent scrolling.

My idea is to make it click/touch through the `div.scroll-overlay`, so `div.content` or whatever inside is clickable whilst `div.scroll-overlay` is still scrollable.

Here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/eliodev/pen/GRjoRbz) illustrating the scenario. It does not reflect fully the `div.content` with many clickable actions inside.

Please advice me if you have any solution in mind. Thanks

Comment: I tried your codepen on an iPad Safari IOS14 and it seems fine, I can both scroll and click the underlying a element. What am I missing?